# How to create a program that prints out a histogram of letters from a txt file in c

Tags: c, file-io, char, histogram, counting

So the program is supposed to take in a txt file with only lowercase letters and no white space. For example "aabbhello". The program will then print out a histogram to the command line:

```
a: 2 
b: 2
h: 1
e: 1
l: 2
o: 1
```

what I currently have should work but always gives me weird outputs:

```
void file_histogram(char *filename)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    int fsize;
    fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(fptr == NULL) {
        printf("File did not open \n");
    }
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fptr);
    char content[fsize];
    rewind(fptr);
    char c;
    int count1 = 0;
    while(fscanf(fptr, "%c", &c) == 1) {
        content[count1] = c;
        count1++;
    }
    char name[fsize];
    int count[26];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < fsize; i++) {
        //printf("%d", i);
        name[i] = content[i];
    }
    int length = strlen(name);
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        count[i] = 0;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        count[content[i] - 'a']++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if(count[i] != 0) {
            printf("%c : %d \n", i + 'a', count[i]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

when I compile the program I print out letters that aren't even in the txt file at some ridiculous high frequency.

```
a : 1
i : 1781796
l : 2
m : 1390299937
n : 32767
w : 1
```

That's what I got when my txt file had "william" as the content. I honestly don't know what's wrong. Does it have to do with the memory maybe? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: And did you attempt to debug your program in any way? Namely with a debugger and/or debug print statements to trace the execution of your program? Please share with us what debugging data you found.

Comment: For the loop that inits `count`: `for(i=0;i<length; i++){` --> `for(i=0;i<sizeof(count)/sizeof(count[0]); i++){`

Comment: i did do some debugging with print statements namely, I printed out content, output was: william. I also printed out how many times the first for loop iterates which is 7 times. So there should only be 7 elements in the array content and name. Each of these arrays should have the chars 'w' 'i' 'l' 'l' 'i''a' 'm'. But the frequency in the output is still completely off. Sometimes there are letters that don't even occur in the name.

Comment: Did you try fixing the for loop as mentioned in my second comment?

Comment: WORKS LIKE A CHARM! thank you. I realized the range of that for loop was wrong. When you create an array in c, the values don't seem to be all at 0.

Comment: Yes, C does not implicitly initalise automatic variables.